# XLSX to JSON converter in protractor. XLSX to JSON default converter not working properly

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

I am stuck with XLSX to JSON coverter as i am unable to find any solution. I am trying to convert XLSX to JSON inside my conf.js. This is how my XLSX look like.
[image: My current excel sheet]

If i am using XLSX to JSON editor, this is how it is showing me.

`[{"":"default","Project1":"smoke"},{"":"Specfile1.js","Project1":"Specfile1.js"},{"":"Specfile2.js","Project1":"Specfile2.js"},{"":"Specfile3.js","Project1":"Specfile3.js"},{"":"Specfile4.js","Project1":"Specfile4.js"},{"":"Specfile5.js","Project1":""},{"":"Specfile6.js","Project1":""},{"":"","Project1":"Project2"},{"":"default","Project1":"smoke"},{"":"Specfile1.js","Project1":"Specfile1.js"},{"":"Specfile2.js","Project1":"Specfile2.js"},{"":"Specfile3.js","Project1":"Specfile3.js"},{"":"Specfile4.js","Project1":"Specfile4.js"},{"":"Specfile5.js","Project1":""},{"":"Specfile6.js","Project1":""}]`

I am not sure how should i format it correctly like

`{
Project1:
{smoke:Specfile1.js,Specfile2.js,Specfile3.js,Specfile4.js,
default: Specfile1.js,Specfile2.js,Specfile3.js,Specfile4.js,Specfile5.js,Specfile6.js
},
Project2:
{smoke: ...,
default: ...,
sanity: .....
}`

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to split projects into sheets. The XLSX spliting column by column ( the first row is a string, next cells in the same column is values) . If you split it into sheets, you will get better result. If you use element by sheet you will get:

```
 {
  "Project1": [
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile1.js",
      "default": "Specfile1.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile2.js",
      "default": "Specfile2.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile3.js",
      "default": "Specfile3.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile4.js",
      "default": "Specfile4.js"
    }
  ],
  "Project2": [
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile1.js",
      "default": "Specfile1.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile2.js",
      "default": "Specfile2.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile3.js",
      "default": "Specfile3.js"
    },
    {
      "smoke": "Specfile4.js",
      "default": "Specfile4.js"
    }
  ],
  "Sanity": [
    {
      "sanity": "Specfile1.js"
    },
    {
      "sanity": "Specfile2.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can access to them like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(test.Project1).length;i++ ) {
     console.log(test.Project1[0].smoke);
}

// Specfile1.js Specfile2.js Specfile3.js Specfile4.js
```